# Lumen Passport return 500 error instead 401 error

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm trying to use lumen passport for our project. I already installed by following this [lumen-passport](https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport). I successfully receive the access_token by doing postman request and here is my code for it.

```
{
 "grant_type": "client_credentials",
 "client_id": "2",
 "client_secret": "1QaxEr6P3K6kKsqa63nA2SMLsczuJJRvufXEDrzY",
 "scope": "*"
}
```

I receive the access token

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 120,
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImJmY2YyYjZlM2I4MTlkMzI3OTE5ODgyMjM0M2NlNjcxM2MyYjFkMjJjZDFiNTQ5ODQ5MjkxMzllMDc2NWJmM2UyZGMyMTMxYTRmYzk1MzNkIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiYmZjZjJiNmUzYjgxOWQzMjc5MTk4ODIyMzQzY2U2NzEzYzJiMWQyMmNkMWI1NDk4NDkyOTEzOWUwNzY1YmYzZTJkYzIxMzFhNGZjOTUzM2QiLCJpYXQiOjE1Njg2MTg4ODksIm5iZiI6MTU2ODYxODg4OSwiZXhwIjoxNTY4NjE5MDA5LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsiKiJdfQ.hIXxn1MJMSS6m2XXrt-EJatMp7KoomzKYnk_McpeeBo9VMYUtKU7tPWCmtw7XpFZFJWvGhIY8cx_A6kTaizFjqEkKmlj3jpjs9X9QUZNQ4J5CwjIcXUAJLRqw6WYvvW94GdPAgUBFz6eIbg_Tzt-149dIwPzlVpd8Ln3Bu84Htj9tiWalkdu5EL6lO_Mc8mFJpAh63fJs84_ES02ex_MACsO52pwfXQLPdrjyWSHPdqDj0hRPVMVMLtPdNtYS12MVf8xg_C6KdcB19viRhmlnQwjl98AXGYt_YeeJozKQax2bSSTqTHfNrBZpka7FZFMznkS3gQ8-9d9FYNSNu3Hiia2ZN44JkolBXB4bNpaa82cj_2yrQ-w8oFivOQqX-dQU7RDD5womVbCd8VmxmtUoTTXdWjridl0F5XasWJfc1N2vTGleY_AGi1qC5_39QXTXsEeesgsiGvq4OJCeIRSLvuuwpFUbV7LVfUvJVL3HSM9-PUBDw0Q2q7mCVLMf_ZLf5s_rNP7uTZOIpZUvUKYXCk4rCB6dE7YIGQZkBr2sOQADd8foMvnxEatwIiJoQCxAEHRgeybmBk4gDUhr-9IoroHxnXrcg2LPulfwe5-hS8cAkjh7OvUuld8W17_TzWOUJq1XPpgWCRomSAB_KeXdyFzrGyVXJTD2r_DU1HbJGE"}
```

in my routes I have these codes.

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'client'], function() use (&$router){
$router->get('example/{id}', 'ExampleController@getData');});
```

Why is it every time the token expires I get 500 error instead 401 error?

I checked the logs in the storage logs and here is the error. I don't know if this is really an error.

```
[2019-09-17 02:39:59] local.ERROR: Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException: Unauthenticated. in /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Middleware/CheckClientCredentials.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials->handle(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(413): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(259): Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(233): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#7 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(169): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)
#8 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(416): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#9 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(171): Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(108): Laravel\Lumen\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#11 /var/www/scheduler-app/public/index.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->run()
#12 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException(code: 0): Unauthenticated. at /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Middleware/CheckClientCredentials.php:48)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckClientCredentials->handle(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#2 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#3 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#4 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(413): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(259): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(233): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#7 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(169): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(Array)
#8 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(416): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#9 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(171): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/scheduler-app/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php(108): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#11 /var/www/scheduler-app/public/index.php(28): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

Comment: Did you check your logs? It looks like there is an other error that's been throwed which means this server gives back a 500 error

Comment: Your route does not require an authenticated user, you can add the auth:api middleware https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#via-middleware (I would guess the error is something like trying to access a property of the user which is null)

Comment: @RolandStarke sorry for late reply. I'm using lumen passport for my project. I think there is distinction between lumen passport and laravel passport. As what I read now. Lumen passport has limited access

Comment: @mukeshkumar sorry for later reply. I checked the logs here `/storage/logs/lumen.log`. see my update post for log error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not the best answer for those developers who know lumen passport, but I figure it out the other way to fix it. I just copy the code from `CheckClientCredentials`, as what I have checked, the code validate the request. here it is

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
    {
        $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

        try {
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        $this->validateScopes($psr, $scopes);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

In my Authentication middleware I add this code.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

        try {
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        // if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
        //     return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        // }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

and the routes I have this

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'client']], function() use (&$router){
    $router->get('example/{id}', 'ExampleController@getData');
});
```

It is working now. I receive 401 error and it validates token if it is not expire.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the middleware, just add something like this to the render method of App\Exceptions\Handler

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException && $request->acceptsJson()) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you for sharing your solution. That worked for me with Lumen 8.3.1 and Passport 0.3.4. Hope they fix / fixed it in newer versions, it should always be 401 and not 500.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution. I have added a check if it is really a 401 error.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
{
    $psr = (new PsrHttpFactory(
        new Psr17Factory,
        new Psr17Factory,
        new Psr17Factory,
        new Psr17Factory
    ))->createRequest($request);

    try {
        $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
    } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {

        if($e->getHttpStatusCode() === 401) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException;

    }

    $this->validate($psr, $scopes);

    return $next($request);
}
```